# Hibernate: updating child object

Tags: java, hibernate

I have such structure:

```
// all objects have valid mapping to database
public class Child {
   private int id;
   private String name;
}
public class Parent {
   private int id;
   private String name;
   private List<Child> chidlren;
}
```

and I have to update specific child B inside parent A.

There are two ways:

1. Update child's fields inside collection and update the whole object:
   `Parent temp = dao.getParent(id);

   temp.getChildren.get(0).setName('test');

   dao.updateParent(temp);`
2. Update only child object:
   `Child temp = dao.getChild(id);

   temp.setName('test');

   dao.updateChild(temp);`

Which one is better if I want to get more perfomance?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to analyse? I would think they would be pretty much the same because hibernate does a lot if optimizing

Comment: My opinion is that the second solution will be faster even with hibernate optimization. If you haven't any additional queries of course. I just wanted to hear another thoughts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the surface, I would surmise that the second solution

> 2.Update only child object

would be more performant.

However, the only way you determine this quantitatively would be to turn on Hibernate's `show_sql`, capture the SQL for Solution 1 and Solution 2, run an Explain Plan for each of your solutions, and compare the resulting Explain Plans.

You could get differing results depending on what else has changed/not changed in the Parent object and other children in the `Parent.children` collection.  When capturing SQL for Explain Plans, you would want to try different scenarios.